# How to reset current object in Java?

Tags: java, object, this, reset

If I have an object myObject of type Foo, while inside myObject, is there a way to reset itself and run the constructor again?

I know the following does not work, but might help convey the idea.

```
this = new Foo();
```

Comment: No, write your own reset method if that is what you need. Otherwise, create a new object and assign it to whichever reference needs it.

Comment: If you want to "reset" an object's state, then you should have a `reset` method that does exactly that.

Answer (score 16):

There is no way to run a constructor again on an existing instance. However, you can organize your code in a way to allow resetting with a minimum amount of work, like this:

```
public class MyClass {
    public MyClass() {
        reset();
    }
    public void reset() {
        // Setup the instance
        this.field1 = ...
        this.field2 = ...
    }
}
```

Note: your reset method needs to set all fields, not just the ones that you usually set in the constructor. For example, your constructor can rely upon the default initialization of reference fields to `null` and numeric fields to zero; your `reset` method needs to set them all explicitly.

Comment: You should clarify this statement: "There is no way to run a constructor again".

Answer (score 7):

It is better to set null or use new Object()

```
obj = null;
   or
obj = new Object();
```

The garbage collector will clear the object finally

Answer (score 2):

An alternative approach, which is gaining in popularity because it tends to make code easier to reason about, is to make your objects *immutable*, and instead of changing their state (e.g. resetting them), simply create a new object.

Answer (score 1):

Just write a method that will "reset" all the variables of your object (null or 0 or default value).

Comment: I am using this method inside a game and have a method called newGame(). I want to be able to call newGame() to start a new game but if I don't overwrite the last game, if someone spams it, there would be a stack overflow error.

Comment: In theory you need a new Object of class Game. This way you will later can save each Game state in some place if you want or accomplish some other requirements as they appear. As I can see you are trying to solve a problem in a structured way with object oriented tools.

Answer (score 1):

Have a set of default values or states for your class stored inside of it.  Then write a `reset()` method that will restore all of these defaults within the class.

```
public void reset(){
    // Reset everything to your default values
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked" })
static void emptyObject(Object obj) 
{
     Class c1 = obj.getClass();
     Field[] fields = c1.getDeclaredFields();

     for(Field field : fields)
     {
          try
          {
               if(field.getType().getCanonicalName() == "boolean")
               {
                    field.set(obj, false);
               }
               else if(field.getType().getCanonicalName() == "char")
               {
                    field.set(obj, '\u0000');
               }
               else if((field.getType().isPrimitive()))
               {
                    field.set(obj, 0);
               }
               else
               {
                    field.set(obj, null);
               }
          }
          catch(Exception ex)
          {

          }
     }}
```